# Loopback update model after save

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to update last inserted/updated document(row) in "after save" hook without create new instance of that like this:

```
Model.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
    ctx.someProperty = 'Foo';
    ctx.update();
});
```

How it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'update' a model. As far as I know, there is no `update()` function on the generic model class. If you're looking for `updateAttribute` then the documentation on that functionality is [here](http://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#persistedmodel-prototype-updateattribute).

However, assuming your question is just "How do I access the observed model inside of a loopback hook?" then the answer is that the instance is stored at `ctx.instance` rather that returned as `ctx` variable itself. See the examples [here](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-beforesave).

E.g.

```
Model.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
    ctx.instance.updateAttributes({someProperty: 'Foo'})
});
```

If you can describe in more detail the functionality you're trying to achieve with the `update()` function, I will try to address that question. **Note also that the code above would probably cause an infinite loop** - because the updateAttribute call will itself trigger the 'after save' hook - which is another reason why I'm not so sure what you're really asking.

Comment: i edit my question. yes,your assumption about my question is true and your hint about infinite loop is true too. is any way to prevent calling 'after save' trigger to resolve infinite loop problem?

Comment: @viam Well, it's probably a design issue. Why is it specifically that you want to update the model? Can you just update the property you're looking to update before you save it, instead of hooking in to update after the fact?

Comment: My purpose was updating a document row  that with your answer it was achieved. infinite loop is another issue. Tnx

Comment: @viam I think you would benefit from rethinking your code organization. Why to you have to update the model on a before save hook? Can it be updated somewhere else that will not cause a loop?

Comment: suppose that i need  to save TableA.id into TableB.AID and then update TableA.BID based on last inserted id from TableB.id. In other words each two tables have relationship together as 'belongsTo' (TableB.AID is belongs to TableA and TableA.BID is belongs to tableB.

Comment: so it need to run in 'after save'  to get ID of TableA and can't be run in 'before save' because access to new inserted id is not possibe , is it true?